# Changing the default behaviour using jquery addClass()/removeClass()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hii I am new to jquery and I want to add/remove the active class to/from the li tag until the other link is clicked for navigation. Currently, I am using the same navigation for all of my Html pages. 
This is my index.html file

```
<body>
    <div id="nav_bar">
        <!-- <a href="navigation/navigation.html">link</a> -->
    </div>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#nav_bar").load("navigation/navigation.html");
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

I've applied the same method for other Html files to and it is working fine.

Navgation.html

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light justify-content-end " id="nav_global ">
        <button class="navbar-toggler " type="button " data-toggle="collapse " data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav " aria-expanded="false " aria-label="Toggle navigation ">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon "></span>
      </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarNav ">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav mr-auto ">
                <li class="nav-item active" id="home ">
                    <a class="nav-link " href="/assignment/index.html ">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item " id="assignment ">
                    <a class="nav-link " href="/assignment/assign/assignment.html ">Assignment</a >
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <script>
        alert("hello from script ");


        $("li.nav-item").click(function(event) {
            let someVar = $(this).hasClass("active");
            alert(someVar);
            if (someVar == false) {
                $("li.nav-item").each(function(i) {
                    $(this).removeClass("active");
                });
                $(this).addClass("active");

            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Now the problem is when I click a link and after the alert is shown the changes are reverting back immediately means that the home is getting active again even after using the removeClass(). Somehow the changes made to the clicked links by addClass are temporarily resulting in the home getting active again. I've used both return false and event.preventDefault() but it is preventing my link to open which I don't want.
I want to make the clicked link li class be active.

ps: sorry for my bad English and explanation. Please feel free to correct my question If you find some error.

Thank you

Comment: Your code is working fine. When i click on home the `active` class is added and when i click on `assignment` the `active` is added to that.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping but not working for me. But can you share with me how you tested it?

Comment: Here is working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/tgu7Lr8c/2/ - Let me know

Comment: The nav links look like real links, so they are going to perform a page transition.  That means your old page, and all the changes made by javascript, are going to be destroyed.  You've already partially discovered this with your attempted usage of returning false and preventingDefault.  The fact that that prevents the page navigation shows your issue.  If you want the classes to persist, you will need to add logic to restore the active class to the desired link after the page is loaded.

Comment: ......or perhaps `event delegation` on dynamically added element from `.load` @Taplar ?

Comment: @Taplar the documentation says that delegate() has been deprecated and was superseded by the .on() method

Comment: @AlwaysHelping event delegation doesn't help this situation, as you need to restore the class state on load, not after an event happens.

Comment: @LazyGy I would not persue any form of event delegation for solving this issue.  You simply need a way, on document ready or page load, to determine which link should be active, and to put the class back on it.

Comment: @Taplar what do you think the correct title for this question should be

Answer (score 0):

Taking just the two links you have in your OP, here is what I would suggest attempting.

```
<script>
    $( () => {
        const data = [
            { suffix: '/index.html', selector: '#home' },
            { suffix: '/assignment.html', selector: '#assignment' }
        ];

        const currentPage = data.find( it =>
            window.location.href.endsWith( it.suffix )
        );

        if ( currentPage ) {
            $( currentPage.selector ).addClass( 'active' );
        }
    } );
</script>
```

On document ready, you create a list of maps, creating a relationship between the url for each page, and the selector for the link to that page.  Then you can find the relationship based on the current url, and if you find one, lookup the link and put the active class on it.